# Smarty how add meta tags from template file

Tags: php, smarty, meta-tags

Example of code that I used in my PHP file:

```
$title = "Test title";
$description = "test description";
$keywords = "test keywords";    
$smarty->assign('title',$title);
$smarty->assign('description',$description);
$smarty->assign('keywords',$keywords);    
$smarty->display('header.tpl');
$smarty->display('private.tpl');
$smarty->display('footer.tpl');
```

### Code used in header.tpl

```
<title>{$title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{$description}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords}" />
```

Is it possible when display different template (example private2.tpl) in same php file to show other tags that in included in .tpl file?
And what code i must insert in my .tpl file (example private2.tpl)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{include file='private2.tpl'}
```